# How to set the color of the circle and the selection dot of a radio button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Python tkinter. I can customize the background color (with "bg" property) and characters' color (with "fg" property) by setting properties of Radiobutton. Now I need:

- a red background and
- white characters

so I created a Radiobutton like this:

```
common_bg = '#' + ''.join([hex(x)[2:].zfill(2) for x in (181, 26, 18)])  # RGB in dec
common_fg = '#ffffff'  # pure white
Radiobutton(paraent_frame, text='abc', variable=radio_value, value=2,
            command=on_click_level_radio, bg=common_bg, fg=common_fg)
```

The GUI seems like this (the black arrow is added by myself):

[image]

But the problem is, the background of the circle of the radio button is white. When the 'little point' which is used to indicate whether the radio is selected, is black by default, it works well. When I set the "fg" property to white, the 'little point' becomes white, too, making it impossible to distinguish whether the radio is selected.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to separately set the color of the 'circle' of the radio button or the 'little point'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.

Actually, the "little point" is the *indicator*, and the "circle" is the *indicator background*.

In your case, the indicator inherits its color from the `foreground`/`activeforeground` options (these are pure white) and the indicator background is pure white by default.

To overcome this, you should set up radiobutton's color properties (you should notice the [`selectcolor`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/radiobutton.htm#M11) option! ):

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

common_bg = '#' + ''.join([hex(x)[2:].zfill(2) for x in (181, 26, 18)])  # RGB in dec
common_fg = '#ffffff'  # pure white

rad_button = tk.Radiobutton(root, text='abc', value=2, fg=common_fg, bg=common_bg,
                            activebackground=common_bg, activeforeground=common_fg, selectcolor=common_bg)

rad_button.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
root.mainloop()
```

Where result is:

[image: result]

However, the docs claims that this option has the system-dependent behavior:

> Specifies a background color to use when the button is selected. If -indicatoron is true then the color applies to the indicator. Under Windows, this color is used as the background for the indicator regardless of the select state. If -indicatoron is false, this color is used as the background for the entire widget, in place of -background or -activeBackground, whenever the widget is selected. If specified as an empty string then no special color is used for displaying when the widget is selected.

So, consider using a `ttk` version of the `radiobutton` with an appropriate [theme](https://wiki.tcl.tk/48689) and [options](http://wiki.tcl.tk/37973#pagetoc757a68e7):

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)

#    try also the 'clam' theme
style.theme_use('alt')

common_bg = '#' + ''.join([hex(x)[2:].zfill(2) for x in (181, 26, 18)])  # RGB in dec
#    alternatively use the "more red" version of the common_bg as the indicatorcolor
#    sel_bg = '#' + ''.join([hex(x)[2:].zfill(2) for x in (221, 26, 18)])
common_fg = '#ffffff'  # pure white

rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='abc')
rad_button.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

style_name = rad_button.winfo_class()
style.configure(style_name, foreground=common_fg, background=common_bg, indicatorcolor=common_bg)

style.map(style_name,
          foreground = [('disabled', common_fg),
                      ('pressed', common_fg),
                      ('active', common_fg)],
          background = [('disabled', common_bg),
                      ('pressed', '!focus', common_bg),
                      ('active', common_bg)],
          indicatorcolor=[('selected', common_bg),
                          ('pressed', common_bg)]

          )
root.mainloop()
```

Where result is:

[image: result]

Theoretically, you could specify separate set of a `bg`/`fg` colors for the both `label` and `indicator`, but problem stems from implementation of the `radiobutton` widget.

If you `print(style.layout(style_name))` you will see this structure:

```
[('Radiobutton.padding',
  {'children': [('Radiobutton.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                ('Radiobutton.focus',
                 {'children': [('Radiobutton.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                  'side': 'left',
                  'sticky': ''})],
   'sticky': 'nswe'})]
```

Later, look for the each element options via `print(style.element_options(element)`:

```
# result of print(style.element_options('Radiobutton.indicator'))
('-background', '-foreground', '-indicatorcolor', '-lightcolor', '-shadecolor', '-bordercolor', '-indicatormargin')

# result of print(style.element_options('Radiobutton.label'))
('-compound', '-space', '-text', '-font', '-foreground', '-underline', '-width', '-anchor', '-justify', '-wraplength', '-embossed', '-image', '-stipple', '-background')
```

Notice that both elements has `'-background'`/`'-foreground'` options, therefore they're both reacts in the same manner, when that option set for the entire style. In other words, `label` and `indicator` share their colors *by design*.

Answer (score 3):

One way around it is to place a label right next to the radio button:

```
l = Label(root, text="abc", fg="white")
l.pack()
```

In which case you'll also need to change the text of the radio button to "". Does that solve the problem?

Comment: It does solve the problem, but the issue is when I click the text part of the Radiobutton the indicator is set, but when I click the Label the indicator doesn't. So if there's no other way this is a good work around, but as Tkinter Radiobutton have such property to set the colors separately as stated by @CommonSense, so this way should not be used