# Changing the background of tkinter checkbutton

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a program with a black background and white foreground.
Everything ( Entries, labels, buttons ) work fine. But when I would make a `checkbutton`, I also would like to make it with black `bg` and white `fg`. I don't know why, but bg="black" doesn't change indicator background ( that little box you are clicking at ) to black. And I can't see the state of `checkbutton`.

[checkbox is on, but I can't see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7LTO.png)

Only when I move a cursor with pressed left button on it, I can see it states:

[image: here]

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Code of checkbutton:

```
self.encryptCheckButton = Checkbutton(self.root, text="Encrypt sended files?",
                                              variable=self.encryptFile,
                                              onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                                              bg="black", fg="white",
                                              activebackground="black",
                                              activeforeground="white")
```

Comment: Try set [`selectcolor='black'`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/radiobutton.htm#M11). Also, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48497928/10364425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, as @Saad says, the `activeforeground` parameter basically takes effect when the mouse **hovers** over the `Checkbutton`, not when you turn it on.

You need to use `selecttcolor` if you want the effect you desire. This will set it black when you select it.

Full code:

```py
self.encryptCheckButton = Checkbutton(self.root, text="Encrypt sended files?",
                                              variable=self.encryptFile,
                                              onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                                              bg="white", selectcolor = "black")
```

If this doesn't work for you, try this:

```py
self.encryptCheckButton = Checkbutton(self.root, text="Encrypt sended files?",
                                              variable=self.encryptFile,
                                              onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                                              bg="black", selectcolor = "white")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this helped for me, i just have set selectcolor to gray.